# How to send notification using multiple time intervals in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.6, nsnotification

I have time intervals in `MutableArray` like

```
NSMutableArray *times=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"6:00 AM", @"6:15 AM", @"6.30 AM", @"6:45 AM", nil];
```

Now i want to display `notifications`, when iphone local system time matches to that `MutableArray` time intervals `notification` has to display at every intervals. Please help me in this problem and send me the code. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps all who are looking out for the solution.

[How To set Custom repeat interval For Nslocal Notification.....?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991771/how-to-set-custom-repeat-interval-for-nslocal-notification)

[How to set Local Notification repeat interval to custom time interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363847/how-to-set-local-notification-repeat-interval-to-custom-time-interval)

[iOS - how to compare two times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595549/ios-how-to-compare-two-times)

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no straight forward way to identify it.

You just need to write a logic on this like first get system's current time and match it with your mutable array and check for the time difference between first time array(Or array which is very close to system time)these two and put up a notification after that time difference change. Then there you go now you can identify when the array time and system time matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `repeatInterval` to repeat the notification.  Try like this..

```
localNotification.repeatInterval=NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
```